# Is there any annotation in Hibernate to define data type of postgres in Entity Class?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity class that connects to the posts table in the PostgreSQL database.

```java
package com.example.enitity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class PostEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    // getters and setters code...
}
```

I am using hibernate and want to specify the Columns Data type like forex.

```java
package com.example.enitity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class PostEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "content")
    @SomeAnnotation(text) // here I want to set content as text in database when it gets created.
    private String content;

    // getters and setters code...
}
```

By default String type objects are getting 'character varying(255)' datatype instead in the database table.
**I also tried @Lob annotation which converts String field to text by default**. But is not giving results when I am doing Spring data JPA operation on it like search etc.(forex. `findByContentContaining(String name)` ). Because it does not perform 'where operation' when we set @Lob annotation. At least that's what I understood by reading about it.

Comment: Try using `@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")` for your column _content_

Comment: It is working thank you.